Get permissions fir API services Connections, Groups, People Search, Invitation
We would like to integrate and synchro our crm with Linkedin. We need to use API services (e.g. Connections, Groups, People Search, Invitation, etc.).
How is it possible to request permission for an access token in order to use Linkedin V2 API?
How can we request permission?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
